# include csv dataset with commas as separator in R package

Tags: r, csv, package

I am bundling a csv dataset with my R package.
The dataset, `dummy.csv`,  is placed into `/data` folder of the package.

If the dataset contains semicolon `;` as field separator, all works fine.
When the package is loaded, and the name of the dataset is typed to the console, fields are correctly recognized. If the same dataset is stored with comma `,` as a field separator, it is not recognized - all fields are read as one string.

I am on Ubuntu Linux.

As per RFC 4180 fields in CSV are to be separated by commas. How do I include a comma separated file to R package?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `read.csv` define the separator (`sep =`) in your command: `read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...)`. Use `?read.csv`for more related information.

Comment: I know that for read.csv you can specify the delimiter. The issue here is that when a dataset is bundled with package, it is loaded with the data() function, e.g. data(iris).

Comment: I see. What is your decimal separator used in the data?